# Search of elements inside a big CSV file using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Im trying to filter a CSV file and get the fifth value of a list that is inside another list , but Im getting out of range all time .

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
teste=[]
f = csv.reader(open('power_supply_info.csv'), delimiter =',' )
for word in f:
    teste.append(word)
    #print teste    
    #print ('\n') 
print map( itemgetter(5), teste)
```

But , I got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rafael.paiva\Dev\Python2.7\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/rafael.paiva/Desktop/Rafael/CSV.py", line 24, in <module>
    print map( itemgetter(5), teste)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What is inside "word" variable , appended to "teste" according with steps is :

```
[['2015-12-31-21:02:30.754271', '25869', '500000', 'Unknown', '1', '0', '4790780', '1', '0', '0', '375', '0', '-450060', '-326040', '3437000', 'Normal', 'N/A', '93', 'Good', '19', '1815372', 'Unknown', 'Charging', '4195078', '4440000', '4208203', '4171093', '0', '44290', 'Li-ion', '95', '1', '3000000', '1', '375', '-450060', '-326040', '3437000', '93', 'Good', '1815372', '4195000', '4440000', '4208203', '4165625', '0', '44290', '95', '3000000', '1', ''],
 ['2015-12-31-21:03:30.910972', '25930', '500000', 'Unknown', '1', '0', '4794730', '1', '0', '0', '377', '0', '55692', '107328', '3437000', 'Normal', 'N/A', '92', 'Good', '19', '1814234', 'Unknown', 'Charging', '4200390', '4440000', '4207734', '4214062', '0', '41200', 'Li-ion', '95', '1', '3000000', '1', '377', '55692', '107328', '3437000', '92', 'Good', '1814234', '4200390', '4440000', '4207734', '4214062', '0', '41200', '95', '3000000', '1', '']]
```

Can someone can help me with it please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you show works correctly with the data sample you have provided:

```
In [8]: l = [['2015-12-31-21:02:30.754271', '25869', '500000', 'Unknown', '1', '0', '4790780', '1', '0', '0'],
   ...:      ['2015-12-31-21:03:30.910972', '25930', '500000', 'Unknown', '1', '0', '4794730', '1', '0', '0']]

In [9]: list(map(itemgetter(5),l))
Out[9]: ['0', '0']
```

I suspect that one line (probably the last line) in your CSV file is blank, therefore the last element of `teste` is actually an empty list, and therefore `itemgetter(5)` fails for that last line.

Instead of cramming everything into a single line, try

```
for item in teste:
    if item:
        print item[5]
```

Comment: Its working in part ! I could get the values , but still its displaying the out of range error =\ .
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
`code Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rafael.paiva\Dev\Python2.7\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/rafael.paiva/Desktop/Rafael/CSV.py", line 32, in <module>
    print item[5]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> `

Comment: OK, then there are lines in the CSV file that have a different structure than most others, and can apparently contain some but fewer than 5 items. You need to find those lines and ignore them/remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You should add some diagnostics to your loop, this will help to show you where a problem might be in your csv file:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

teste = []

with open('power_supply_info.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    for line, words in enumerate(csv.reader(f_input, delimiter =',' ), start=1):
        if len(words) <= 5:
            print "Line {} only has {} elements".format(line, len(words))
        teste.append(words)

print map(itemgetter(5), teste)
```

It is likely that one of you lines is either blank or has too few entries, this script will list which lines numbers have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's in your `power_supply_info.csv` file, but it's clear what you have after  `csv.reader` has done its job:

- a list with **2** lists (ie: **2** elements)

That's why you get an error accessing the **5th** element, there are only **2**

A possible approach for your problem:

```
import csv

f = csv.reader(open('power_supply_info.csv'), delimiter =',' )
# First iterate over the rows and then get each list in the row
teste = [x for x in (row for row in f)]
print map(lambda x: x[5], teste)
```

The real challenge would be to see the input you have in your **csv** file to understand why you end up with those 2 lists inside a list.

Note: In case you output belongs to **teste** and not to **word**, the code could be:

```
import csv

f = csv.reader(open('power_supply_info.csv'), delimiter =',' )
teste = [row for row in f]
print [x[5] for x in teste]
```

Best regards

Comment: He's not accessing the fifth element in the list, he's accessing the fifth element of each sub-list contained within the list. And those are long enough, at least most of them are.

Comment: His question says literally "What is inside "word" variable ..." and that's why my answer contains 2 pieces of code. One to cover his statement and another to cover the possible reality. Thank you for not reading.

Comment: I agree his question was ambiguous. However, his further comments have clarified that the problem is not the size of the list, and this was also clear from his use of `itemgetter()` because it's being used in a way (with `map()`) that it can only access the sublists, not the "main list with only 2 elements". So I guess you didn't quite do all the reading either. A revenge downvote is not really the solution to this (especially since I didn't downvote your post), now is it?

Comment: Ambiguous and my answer was posted before he commented your answer indicating it was working in part (which is then clarifying). My answer has a "0" and I have not implied and/or stated you have downvoted it